# How to create layout like this in android?

Tags: android

I want to create one screen where I can click image of card as shown in below given image.

[image]

I have created screen like this with code as given below and this code actually works but I'm just not sure how to add that card cutout layout on this.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlCamera"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
                android:id="@+id/viewFinder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:alpha="0.5"
                android:background="@color/black" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_15sdp">

                    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_34sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_34sdp"
                        android:alpha="0.2"
                        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_50sdp" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_15sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_15sdp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
                        android:tint="@color/white" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_25sdp"
                    android:text="License"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_120sdp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
                        android:id="@+id/viewFinderCard"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_40sdp" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_40sdp"
                        android:text="Front of card"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_70sdp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:text="All 4 corners should be aligned to card given above."
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />

                </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgCapture"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_54sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_54sdp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_40sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_capture" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Result

[image]

But now I'm not sure how to add the transparent cutout for card image rectangle.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: try with Frame Layout

Comment: I have already done that with relative layout but how to show that transparent cutout and whole layout is with alpha value given and it all works nice just not sure how to add that card shaped full transparent rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to use [9-patch](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch) bitmap for such cutout. if some `ViewGroup` have solid/semitransparent/image as a background then its hard to "cut out" some part of it from child side, you should override `onDraw` then and make some manual math and job on `Canvas`... it should be at least `drawable`, but your sample isn't easy to be made programmatically (especially colooured corners).

would be way easier to set 9-patch as background for whole layout in place of currently set `"@color/black"` and `alpha`. be aware of content and stretch areas and set some `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` (or fixed) for frame with card preview. 9-patch will wrap it nicely